How to Map GridDB Data Types to Laravel Eloquent Models When Using the GridDB PHP Client?
I'm building a Laravel application where I need to store and retrieve data from GridDB. I've successfully established a connection to GridDB and can perform basic operations like creating containers and inserting data.
However, I'm facing challenges with mapping GridDB data types to Eloquent model attributes.
What I've Done:

I have a container in GridDB with the following schema:
id (INTEGER)
sensor_id (STRING)
value (DOUBLE)
timestamp (TIMESTAMP)

Laravel Eloquent Model:


<?php



namespace App\Models;



use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;



class SensorData extends Model
{
protected $table = 'sensor_data';
protected $primaryKey = 'id';
public $incrementing = false;
public $timestamps = false;



protected $fillable = [
'id',
'sensor_id',
'value',
'timestamp',
];



protected $casts = [
'id' => 'integer',
'sensor_id' => 'string',
'value' => 'double',
'timestamp' => 'datetime',
];
}


Data Retrieval:

$data = SensorData::where('sensor_id', 'sensor_001')
->whereBetween('timestamp', [$startDate, $endDate])
->get();

and for this i get:
Undefined Table or Column:
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mydatabase.sensor_data' doesn't exist

If I try to fetch data directly using the GridDB PHP client and map it to the model, I get errors related to data type mismatches, especially with the timestamp field.
How can I correctly map GridDB data types to Laravel Eloquent model attributes?

I do not know GridDB, but does the sensor_data table already exist, or was it created via migration? ... Having that info in the SensorData model will NOT automatically create the table, if that's what you might be expecting.
